# Can't locate XML/LibXML.pm

Tags: xml, perl, activeperl, xml-libxml

I installed Strawberry Perl on my windows XP operating system. Later I tried to execute the .XML file but it's throwing error as below. I also tried Active Perl and also getting the same error.

I am running the following code in the command prompt:

```
C:> perl xcp_conf.pl FILENAME.xml
```

> ERROR: can't locate XML/LibXML.pm in @INC contains: C:/Perl/site/Lib C:/perl/Lib at xcp_conf.pl

Could you please tell me where to download the above file? How to install that package?

Comment: You need to install `XML::LibXML`.

Answer (score 16):

try this :

```
perl -MCPAN -e shell
# at prompt type in :  install XML::LibXML
```

another way is to use ppm and select package you are interested.

Comment: Reference for cpan shell: https://perldoc.perl.org/CPAN#NAME

Answer (score 3):

You can also install it using [CPAN](https://www.cpan.org/): `cpan XML::LibXML`

Answer (score 1):

Please try it:

```
ppm install XML-LibXML
```

For more details:
https://code.activestate.com/ppm/XML-LibXML/